# Determine if file IO is closed on OS X

Tags: macos, file-io, filesystems, inotify

I want to trigger an event on OS X -- could be from the command line, or Obj-C -- when IO is closed on a particular file (rather than file modified).

On linux this is easy, inotify provides IN_CLOSE_WRITE events.

But on OS X FSEvent only signals modifications under some directory; it doesn't seem like it provides any information about whether IO is complete.

Comment: I'm also looking for a solution on this.